# discord.py coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try to run the command I always get this error message: discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.unban' raised an error: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.**call**' was never awaited

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class unban(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

# Commandok

@commands.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member): # unindent
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans() # unindent
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#') # unindent

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
    return

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(unban(client))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
File "K:\Discord BOT\PythonX\Bot.py", line 74, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
  File "C:\Users\NexaHn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 663, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\NexaHn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 623, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.unban' raised an error: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
```

Comment: unban is not a cog. It is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Administration(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def unban(self, ctx,*,member):
        # your function 

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Administration(bot))
```

Look this -> https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html